# Process HTML Markup in C#

Tags: c#, html, string-parsing

I want to process/manipulate some HTML markup

**e.g.**

```
<a id="flFileList_gvDoItFiles_btnContent_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('flFileList$gvDoItFiles$ctl03$btnContent','')">Untitled.png.3154ROGG635264188946573079.png</a>
```

changed to

```
<a id="flFileList_gvDoItFiles_btnContent_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('flFileList$gvDoItFiles$ctl03$btnContent','')">Untitled.png</a>
```

I want achieve this using C# string processing.

Not getting any idea for this.
I have logic written convert

**Untitled.png.3154ROGG635264188946573079.png**  to

**Untitled.png**

I am stuck in how do I identify and replace th string in markup?

```
String.Split()??
```

Comment: try this library -> http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML. You can easily get `a` element by it's id, and then replace it's inner text:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html_string);
string xpath = "//a[@id='flFileList_gvDoItFiles_btnContent_1']";
var a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
a.InnerHtml = ConvertValue(a.InnerHtml); // call your logic for converting value
string result = a.OuterHtml;
```